# Data composition for regression modelling

Tags: regression, predictive-models

A question of regression model building for “Yes” and “No” answers.

Data of 6,000 products of same type and same model, 1,080 of them (18%) are indicated with problems (fail to meet product standard).

Is this data sufficient enough for building a perdition model to predict the likelihood of a manufacturing failure?

If the percentage was much lower to 2%, will it be different? (without any other details than the given limited information)

Thank you.

Comment: This question seems unanswerable to me. It depends entirely on how much information your predictors contain about manufacturing failure.